# Erro no angularJS quando salvo data, por que?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<form name="formProfissional">
    <label>Data</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="dia" ng-model="agenda.dia" required>
    <label>Hora</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="time" name="hora" ng-model="agenda.hora" required>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btnAdicionar" ng-click="setAgenda(agenda)">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

E esse controller:

```
app.controller("AgendaProfissionaisCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

$rootScope.idestabelecimento = localStorage.getItem('idestabelecimento');
$scope.idprofissional = $routeParams.idprofissional;

// $scope.nome;
var getPro = function(){
    var idpro = $scope.idprofissional;
    var opcao = 1; //Pegar profissional

$http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/Android/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/agendaProfissionais.php?opcao="+opcao+"&idpro="+idpro).success(function(response){
        $scope.nome = response.nome;
    })
}

getPro();

$scope.setAgenda = function(agenda){
    agenda.idpro = $scope.idprofissional;
    var mes  = new Date(agenda.dia).getMonth() + 1;
    var dia  = new Date(agenda.dia).getDate();
    var ano  = new Date(agenda.dia).getFullYear();

    var hora  = new Date(agenda.hora).getHours();
    var min  = new Date(agenda.hora).getMinutes();

    agenda.dia = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;
    agenda.hora = hora+':'+min;
    console.log(agenda)
}


}]);
```

E no console, apesar de aparecer os dados corretos, aparece esse aviso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o por que desse aviso?

Comment: Versão do Angular?

Comment: angular.js é v1.4.7 já a angular.min.js é v1.5.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na *view* você está definindo `agenda.dia` como um `date`:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="dia" ng-model="agenda.dia" required>
```

Porém com a linha

```
agenda.dia = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;
```

você está convertendo o objeto para uma *string*. Para manter o tipo `date`, altere para:

```
agenda.dia = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
```

Se você deseja preservar, por algum motivo, a string contendo a descrição do dia, crie uma outra propriedade.

Para preservar o valor `hora`, você pode utilizar um dos *overloads* de Date() que aceita especificação de horas e minutos:

```
agenda.hora = new Date(0,0,0,hora,min);
```

Comment: Eita, você voltou :p

Comment: @LINQ Eu nunca fui, só entrei em modo *lurker* até entregar um projeto. ;)

Comment: Beleza, e pra fazer o mesmo com a data, que está apontando o mesmo erro, seria:
new Date(hora, min)?

Comment: @GustavoSevero eu modifiquei a resposta, adicionando a parte relevante à propriedade `hora`.

Comment: Deu isso no console:
Object {dia: Mon Jul 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03), hora: Invalid Date, idpro: "1", opcao: 2}

Comment: @GustavoSevero oops! Corrigido. =)

Comment: Beleza, mas veja como ficou o mês na data...
Object {dia: Mon Jul 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03), hora: Sun Dec 31 1899 17:45:00 GMT-0200 (-02), idpro: "1", opcao: 2}
Eu precisava do mês em número kkkkk

Comment: @GustavoSevero das duas, uma: Ou você preserva o objeto Date (que na verdade é apenas um valor numérico indicando milisegundos desde um ponto no passado chamado *epoch*) ou separa os valores, como você fez (por exemplo `agenda.dataDia`, `agenda.dataMes`) - porém não sobrescrevendo a propriedade esperada pelo modelo (`agenda.data`).

Comment: Mas não estou sobrescrevendo... Cada elemento da data eu coloco em uma variável separada.

Comment: @GustavoSevero no momento em que `agenda.hora = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;` é executado, a propriedade é sobrescrita. `setAgenda(agenda)` está passando $scope.agenda, o modelo, como referência.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque a partir da versão 1.3 do AngularJS, os inputs com tipo `date` precisam ter um `ng-model` que seja uma data válida.

O `agenda.dia` é uma string, por isso acontece este erro.

O código deveria ser

```
agenda.dia = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
```

[Você ler sobre isso na página relativa a este erro](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z).